# Typekit 404 - https://use.typekit.net/.js

Tags: typekit

I implement typekit on my website.

And it works fine! I got my fonts!

But i got following error on the web console:

```
https://use.typekit.net/.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I implement it like this:

```
  <script src="//use.typekit.net/{here i put my code}.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
```

It seems that the typekit script try to load the file https://use.typekit.net/.js

But the fonts are still loded!

Answer (score -3):

`{here i put my code}`.js is the problem. Between the `{}` is just an example, but you need to change this to a real js name like this: thisismyjs.js

Comment: I write "{here i put my code}" just before i postet it here. Just to hide my personal code ;)